# checkbox in datatble using primefaces5

Tags: jsf-2, checkbox, primefaces, datatable

I have a problem with my datatable.

I try to display selected rows of a table but I can't because my selection list is empty even if I check one or more rows.it seems that I have a selectedArticles empty I don't know what part of my code should I change .I m asking for your help please.
My jsf page :

```
<h:body>

     <h:form id="form">
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />

<p:panel header="Order" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
        <p:outputLabel for="category" value="Category: " />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="category" value="#{catBean.category}" var="line" style="width:150px">
          <p:ajax listener="#{catBean.onCategoryChange}" update="product" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Category" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{catBean.myItems}"  />      
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:outputLabel for="product" value="" />
        <p:dataTable id="product" var="line" value="#{catBean.myProducts}" selection="#{catBean.selectedItems}" style="margin-bottom:0" rowKey="#{line.cdProduct}">

         <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
         <p:column headerText="Code">
        <h:outputText value="#{line.cdProduct}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="title" >
        <h:outputText value="#{line.title}" />
        </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton process="product" update=":form:multiProductDetail" icon="ui-icon-search" value="View" oncomplete="PF('multiProductDialog').show()" />
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog header="Products" widgetVar="multiProductDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false" width="auto">
    <p:outputPanel id="multiProductDetail" style="text-align:center;">
        <ui:repeat value="#{catBean.selectedItems}" var="line">
            <h:outputText value="#{line.cdProduct} -- #{line.title}" style="display:block"/>
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:outputPanel>
  </p:dialog>

        </h:panelGrid>

     </p:panel>  
</h:form>    
</h:body>
</html>
```

my managedBean contains this attributes

```
@ManagedBean(name="catBean")
@ViewScoped


public class catBean  implements Serializable {


private String cdCategory;
private String category;
private List<SelectItem> myItems;
private List<Product> selectedItems=new ArrayList<Article>();

{geters and setters...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the `<p:dataTable value>` is filled by a `<p:selectOneMenu><p:ajax listener>`, and thus the availability of the `<p:dataTable value>` for selection is dependent on the view scope, you need to make absolutely sure that the bean is also view scoped. Otherwise the `<p:dataTable value>` would default to `null` during postback and nothing would be available for selection.

Those annotations are good,

```
@ManagedBean(name="catBean")
@ViewScoped
public class catBean  implements Serializable {
```

but you need to make sure that you import them both from `javax.faces.bean` package. If you import the `@ViewScoped` from `javax.faces.view`, then the bean will behave like `@RequestScoped`. The `javax.faces.view` is only when you use `@Named` instead of `@ManagedBean`.

Comment: Thank you very very much @BalusC it was the cause of my problem ..really you're the best (y)