# Saving p:dataTable selectionMode="multiple" for all different models on same table in same view

Tags: jsf-2, checkbox, primefaces

I have a datatable that contains checkbox and I want that when a user selects one or more items .. the list of his choices will be displayed in another page jsf

I have a selectOneMenu that allows the user to select a category(a datatable is filled with products from this category)..user can select one or more products from this table..The list of choices is displayed in another jsf page .. 
I want that user can select items from the categiory 1 and add to this list articles from another category (2 or 3...) .. My problem is that once the user switches to another category (in the selectOneMenu)the list of choices is not recorded and if it goes to the confirmation page .. list of choices contains only the last items selected..Some one can tell me how can I save the chackbox choices even if the user select another category?

The code is visible in my previous question: [checkbox in datatble using primefaces5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427367/checkbox-in-datatble-using-primefaces5)

---

this are the changes I have done in my jsf ..But my problem persist ..Can you help me to find what wrong in my code (because even if @BalusC have generously offered me the above solution which seems very logical I don't know where is my mistake)Any guidance will be appreciated.Thanks in advance :)

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="category" value="#{catBean.category}" valueChangeListener="#{catBean.changeCategory}" var="line" style="width:150px">
       <p:ajax listener="#{catBean.onCategoryChange}" update="product" />
       <p:ajax process="product" listener="#{catBean.updateProducts}" update="product" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Category" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{catBean.myItems}"  />  
      </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:outputLabel for="product" value="" />
        <p:dataTable id="product" var="line" value="#{catBean.myProducts}" selection="#{catBean.selectedItems}" style="margin-bottom:0" rowKey="#{line.cdProduct}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On change of the dropdown, process the data table as well, remember the previous selection via a `valueChangeListener`, copy the current selection into a `Map` and restore the new selection from it in the ajax listener method:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.category}" valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeCategory}">
    ...
    <p:ajax process="@this products" listener="#{bean.updateProducts}" update="products" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:dataTable id="products" value="#{bean.products}" selection="#{bean.selection}" ...>
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

With

```
private String category;
private String previousCategory;
private List<Product> products;
private List<Product> selection;
private Map<String, List<Product>> selections = new HashMap<>();

public void changeCategory(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    previousCategory = (String) event.getOldValue();
}

public void updateProducts() {
    selections.put(previousCategory, selection);
    products = productService.find(category);
    selection = selections.get(category);
}
```

Comment: This was just a stub. Just do whatever you already did in `onCategoryChange` (retrieving products based on selected category, obviously)

Comment: Oh!that's stronge O.o it's exactly what I have done(I have called exactly the same method used in the onCategoryChange )but as I said the selected items are not saved once I change my seletOneMenu value I lose all the previous values

Comment: Works for me. Did you add the table to the `<p:ajax process>` as indicated in the answer?

Comment: Yes absolutly..but I have change one things..I put my managedbean as `@SessionScoped` because I have to sent the list of my select items to another jsf page and with `@ViewScoped` it doesn't work

Comment: Okay. You'd better conditionally render the view, but that's a different problem. You're able to retain the selection across changes of the dropdown, right? That was what I answered.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59936/discussion-on-answer-by-balusc-saving-pdatatable-selectionmodemultiple-for-a).